# LaTeX - Indent to a specified position

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I am trying to figure out how to indent specific lines to specific locations.

There are **two** things I was able to do using "brute force."

[image]

And here is the code I used to produce that:

```
\documentclass[a4,12pt] {article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\thispagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}


\begin{flushleft}


\textbf{List name} \\
\vspace{-2ex}
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
- This is a sentence I am typing here (1) \hfill Feb 2019 –- Nov 2020 \\
\-\hspace{0.19cm} And this is the sentence below it (1.1) \\

\vspace{1cm}

\textbf{The name of the other list} \\
\vspace{-2ex}
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
- This is a sentence I am typing here (2) \hspace{7.5cm} 2020 \\
\-\hspace{0.19cm} And this is the sentence below it (2.1)  \\


\end{flushleft}


\end{document}
```

1. Using the command `\-\hspace{0.19cm}` I kept tweaking the distance until I got the 'A' in 'And' to start where the 'T' in 'This' does.
2. Using the command `\hspace{7.5cm}` I was able to get the '2' in '2020' to start where the 'F' in 'Feb' does.

Is there a better way of doing these two things?

Moreover, something that I can not even start thinking of how to do is: How can I position "2020" such that it is in the center of "Feb. 2019 - Nov 2020"? Roughly like this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! This can be solved easily with a `tabular` environment. Note that the option of your `\documentclass` should be `a4paper`, and you don’t seem to actually use the packages `ragged2e` and `setspace`.

Comment: Do not forget that LaTeX provides a `tabbing` environment too.  Depending on your needs, it might, or might not, be appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straight-forward way to do this is perhaps to use a `tabular` environment where you can set the width and alignment of the different columns.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
%\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{array,calc}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}

\textbf{List name} \\
\vspace{-2ex}
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
\begin{tabular}{ @{} p{1em} @{} p{\textwidth-11em} @{} >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{10em} @{} }
-- & This is a sentence I am typing here (1) & Feb 2019 -- Nov 2020 \\
   & And this is the sentence below it (1.1) & \\
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1cm}

\textbf{The name of the other list} \\
\vspace{-2ex}
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
\begin{tabular}{ @{} p{1em} @{} p{\textwidth-11em} @{} >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{10em} @{} }
-- & This is a sentence I am typing here (2) & 2020 \\
   & And this is the sentence below it (2.1) & \\
\end{tabular}

\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Let me shortly explain the column definitions. Please also inform yourself about the `tabular` environment and read the relevant parts of the [documentation of the `array`package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/array).

- `@{}` sets the horizontal padding between the current and the following cell column to zero.
- `p{1em}` defines a column of cells with the width of 1em. Each cell is a box containing a paragraph that allows for line breaks.
- `p{\textwidth-11em}` defines a column of cells with the width of the text body minus the width of 11em. You need the `calc` package for such calculations. (In the definition, there is one column with the width of 1em and one with the width of 10em, so the third column should have the width of `\textwidth-11em` to make the whole table span the whole width of the text body.)
- `>{\centering\arraybackslash}` sets the text in the following cell column to be centered. `\arraybackslash` is needed for technical reasons (see the documentation of the `array` package).

If you want more columns, you need to edit the defintion of columns accordingly. Note that the number of defined columns must fit the number of cells that you enter for each row using `&` or `\\`.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you very much! If my understanding is correct, the "parameters" that the tabular environment accept are   \begin{tabular}[pos]{cols}

And in the code you kindly provided, you have specified certain conditions for the {cols} parameters, right? Now, after playing around with the code, I think the conditions restrict the columns of the table to be only 3, correct? Because when I try to add other columns, the code breaks.

Comment: @Aziz I added some explanations to my answer. I hope this helps you to understand how `tabular` environments and the `array` package work. You can add more columns, but then the number in your definition must fit the number of cells of each row. Also, you need to adjust the width of the columns.